# Root of integer difference equation

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, discrete

I have a function `f[k]` where `k` is a nonnegative integer. My function `f` has a single point where it attains its maximum (though is not necessarily discrete-concave): it occurs at the first time when the difference `f[k+1]-f[k]<=0`. Is there a way I can ask Mathematica to solve for such a `k`? Ideally there would be a functional expression for the optimal `k`.

As a simple example, consider the problem of finding the index of the last positive element in a vector of sorted (descending) values. Is there a Mathematica function that I can use to solve something like `Solve[DifferenceDelta[f[k], k] == 0]`?

```
x := {10, 9, 6, 5, 2, 2, -1, -3, -4}
f[k] := Sum[x[i], {i, 1, k}]
```

In this specific case, I don't see a better way of identifying the optimal `k` besides evaluating each difference and checking its sign, so I don't expect Mathematica to provide an expression for the optimal `k`.

EDIT: to clarify, I am interested in approaches that will work for general `f`, not just this particular example.

Comment: `LengthWhile` ?

Comment: @imidak: thanks, i see how this would solve my particular example of `f`, but i am curious about code i can write to ask mathematica to return an expression like that for general `f`

Comment: If you have some sort of upper bound on `k`, you can do something like `Maximize[{f[k], Element[k, Integers] && 0 < k < kmax}, k]`

Answer (score 1):

This works when there are no duplicates:

```
Position[x,Last@Select[x, Positive]]
```

Comment: thanks, i see how this would solve my particular example of f, but i am curious about code i can write to ask mathematica to return an expression like that for general f

Answer (score 1):

Just to promote discussion:

Using  `x := {10, 9, 6, 5, 2, 2, -1, -3, -4}`

You can find position of maximum:

```
mx = Max[Accumulate@x]
Position[Accumulate@x, mx]
```

yields 34 and {{6}}

You could use [`Differences`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Differences.html) and [`FirstPosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html)

```
FirstPosition[Differences[Accumulate[x]], _?(# <= 0 &)]
```

yields {6}